Youtube metada on production
im doing simple link preview feature in my app.

Everything works fine on dev but youtube has some problems on deploy
Thats how response look like on development:

And thats how it looks like on production:

Other links like spotify etc looks fine, the main problem is youtube dont return me their metadata on prod.
Is there any way to get their metadata on prod without extra packages/logic?
